# Specify a datetime.date without a day in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Is there a way to specify a `datetime.date` without a day like that:

```
datetime.date(year=1900, month=1, day=None)
```

I have a dataset with not full specified dates (sometimes only the year and the month is in it). I want to reprepsent that with a `datetime.date` without doing tricks.

Comment: Is there any issue with setting day to 1?

Comment: I don't pretend to speak for the OP, but I've worked on legal systems where there's a *big* difference between values like '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-??'. See this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6066/1064

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Beautiful is better than ugly. Explicit is better than implicit..."* - [Python's Philosophy](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

You cannot do that by built-in `datetime.date`. Python `datetime.date` doesn't have function signature as not to put the day value. Perhaps it is due to the fact that `date` without `day` (of month) is naturally an incomplete date in real life.

Additionally, since `day` input is seen as `Integer` thus it must have value. And the default integer value as 0 will cause day representation error (albeit the internal mechanism for counting `datetime` might work around with it), as our `day` in real life starts with 1. In short, `datetime.date` has done a pretty good job (in terms of safe of use) - consistent with its "Explicit is better than implicit philosophy" - by not letting the user to call it without specifying day (that is: by hinting what is required in the function signature as what every good programmer would do).

But, you could create your own function wrapper whenever you feel it is annoying or unnecessary too.

Edit:

or using Python's own wrapper:

```
monthdate = functools.partial(datetime.date, day=1) #edit by ShadowRanger
```

To me, what seems to be the simplest practice would be to use the current built-in with the value of `day` as 1.

```
datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)
```

It is a very short `,1` to be added

Comment: No need to roll your own wrapper, Python provides the batteries: `monthdate = functools.partial(datetime.date, day=1)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I wasn't aware of that. I put up your option in the answer, referring it to you.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.date` represents a day in Gregorian calendar. It is immutable and therefore all values must be known at the instant it is created. You can't omit the day if you use the constructor explicitly.

> I have a dataset with not full specified dates

`datetime.strptime()` provides the default values if necessary:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2016-02', '%Y-%m').date()
datetime.date(2016, 2, 1)
```